# form validation not working while submitting form

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I've created a form and the functionality is working properly but I'm facing some issue with validations.

The validations are not working, I want to restrict the form to submit if there's any error in the form and also want to apply the validation for email (if it's an email field), text input and number input.

You can review my code here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ay58g9

Comment: do you want to disable submit button or what?

Comment: not disable but the form should not get submitted and the error messages should show. Also, the email validations are not wokring

Comment: Check this:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ye9put

Comment: Thanks for your quick help, but the submit button is always disabled

Comment: Then @eliseo's answer will help!

Answer (score 0):

please try this one. I'm using angular material so please also look on it

```
<form name="f" (ngSubmit)="f.form.valid && submitForm(f)" #f="ngForm" novalidate>
  <mat-form-field class="w-100">
    <mat-label>First Name</mat-label>
    <input type="text" matInput name="firstName" [(ngModel)]="data.firstName" #firstName="ngModel" required>
    <mat-error *ngIf="firstName.invalid">
      <span *ngIf="firstName.errors.required">Firstname Is Required</span>
    </mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>

  <mat-form-field class="w-100">
    <mat-label>Email</mat-label>
    <input type="text" matInput name="email" [(ngModel)]="data.email" #email="ngModel" required
      pattern="^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$" required (keyup)="findDuplicateUserEmail(f)">
    <mat-error *ngIf="email.invalid">
      <span *ngIf="email.errors && email.errors.required">Email Is Required</span>
      <span *ngIf="email.errors && email.errors.pattern"> Email Is Incorrect</span>
    </mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>

  <button type="submit" mat-raised-button color="primary">Create</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I like

```
<!--pass the form-->
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="submit(form)">
```

In the .ts

```
submit(form:FormGroup)
{
   if (form.valid)
   {
             ..here you get something with the form.value..
   }
   else
      form.markAllAsTouched() //<--to show errors
}
```